# xfce4:When i try to enable the execute box It's not there .-

Tags: permissions, xfce

When i downloaded an .jar file an try'd to execute it a box pop'd up saying "the file has no permission to execute this file" so i right click and click on permission and in the permission box there is supposed to be an "Enable execute" or something but in my case there it's not there for some reason?

Any help will be apreciated

Comment: Try to open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run  `java -jar yourfile.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the permission with chmod some times setting execute permission by the GUI may not work.  You need to give the full path of the file or fodder with this command.

```
sudo chmod ugo+wrx /home/user/Downloads/forge.jar -v
```

And you should be able to right click execute.

Comment: The terminal says "failed to change mode of 'file.jar' from 0000 (---------) to 0000 (---------)" any help?

Comment: change `file.jar` to the file you want to be executable. `file.jar` is just an example.

Comment: But the same thing happens but with the file name :c

Comment: @reyce can you post the full output of the command.  and where is the file located ?

Comment: hmm okay i'll look for it

Comment: The file is located in "/home/user/Downloads/"  File name "forge.jar"  Command imputed "sudo chmod ugo+wrx forge.jar -v" but then it just says "forge.jar' from 0000 (---------) to 0000 (---------)"

Comment: @reyce edited my answer.

Comment: don't worry i found a way to make it executable.I just sent the executable file too the desktop and then marked it as executable there, but anyway thanks for the help.